# Azure power shell command to remove IP restrictions on App service

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-app-service-envrmnt, azure-application-gateway

I did my part of RnD and could not find Azure Powershell command remove IP restrictions on App service. Can someone help me out here plz.

Comment: Any update? If my reply solved your issue, please mark it as answer. If not, please show me the error, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try the command below, it works fine on my side.

```
$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "yourresourcegroup" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourappservicename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01
$p = $r.Properties
$p.ipSecurityRestrictions = @()
Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  "yourresourcegroup" -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourappservicename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 -PropertyObject $p
```

[image]