# Azure portal won't load IP restrictions after addition, cannot remove restriction

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I added a test-restriction in our development environment a few minutes ago. After seeing that it worked and indeed blocks acess to the site, I went back to remove it. 30 minutes later and "app service -> networking -> IP restrictions" is still loading.

The entire test-team is jsut sitting without any access. Disaster. What can be done?

Comment: You could check  `ipSecurityRestrictions`  in the `azure resource explorer`, if it still exists, you could try to follow the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715427/azure-power-shell-command-to-remove-ip-restrictions-on-app-service/50715967#50715967) to use powershell to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still an issue, to isolate, check to see if its specific to a WebApp or happens on all the WebApps ((networking -> IP restrictions blade loading..) you have provisioned. Also, isolate the issue to see if its a browser specific issues, by accessing the ‘IP restrictions blade’ on another browser. 
As Joy mentioned ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50715427/azure-power-shell-command-to-remove-ip-restrictions-on-app-service/50715967#50715967)), you could remove the IP restrictions via PowerShell.

$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName "yourresourcegroup" -ResourceType 
  Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourappservicename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01

$p = $r.Properties

$p.ipSecurityRestrictions = @()

Set-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName  "yourresourcegroup" -ResourceType 
  Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName yourappservicename/web -ApiVersion 2016-08-01 
  -PropertyObject $p